# JPA @Pre and @Post callbacks not called

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with JPA on top of Hibernate.

I have to make some of the entities to have special auditing feature. I can simply implement it using the `@PrePersist` / `@PostPersist` callbacks in the entity class.

I would like to put this callbacks in a base class. However if this base class is a simple java class without the `@Entity` annotation then the callbacks are not called. 
If I put `@Entity` annotation on the base class as well then I got an error `Table 'my_base_class_entity' doesn't exist`.

**This works:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class JpaDocument {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        logger.debug("PrePersist started");
    }

}
```

**This doesn't** (The callback function is not called)

```
public abstract class SpecialEntity {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        logger.debug("PrePersist started");
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class JpaDocument extends SpecialEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

}
```

Probably I should add `@Entity` annotation to my `SpecialEntity` class but it forces me to add primary key, what I don't want as it not always the same among child entities. Besides this `SpecialEntity` has no database relation, it is not a real entity.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-mapped-superclass, https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: Oh, that's it. It works fine with the `@MappedSuperclass`. Many thanks!

Comment: @Vmxes can you please post this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple. Thanks to @JB_Nizet comment.
Instead of `@Entity` annotation the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation was added to the base class and so it works fine.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SpecialEntity {
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        logger.debug("PrePersist started");
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "document")
public class JpaDocument extends SpecialEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ...

}
```